# Typescript array object should take particular shape based on particlar key in object

Tags: typescript

So I have an array-object in typescript. I want object to follow particular structure based on the key value i.e

```
let a = [
   {key: 'textInput', defaultProps: {//textInputValues}}, 
   {key: 'image', defaultProps: {//images values}}
],
```

In `a`, if the key is textInput then defaultProps should only have props for that textInput.

Top level, I have an [open source component rn-formly](https://github.com/blendtale/rn-formly) which I am trying to move in typescript

From the example

```
const inputFields = [
  {
    key: 'name', 
    type: 'text', 
    label: `Your Full Name`,
    required: true,
    helper: 'Using your real name would make it more likely for you to get a match',
    templateOptions: { 
      componentProps: {
        placeholder: 'Frank Murphy'
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    key: 'otp', 
    type: 'otp', 
    label: 'Enter OTP',
    helper: '(optional) but try to enter incorrect date', 
    templateOptions: {
      noOfTextInput: 5,
    }
  }]
```

If type for the iterated object is 'text', I want templateOptions to take props for textInput.

Similar if the type is `otp` (second object in the array), I want the user to write props for otp component.

Any Idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface TextStuff {
    key: 'text'
    templateOptions: {
        componentProps: {
            placeholder: string;
        }
    }
}

interface OtpStuff {
    key: 'otp',
    templateOptions: {
        noOfTextInput: number
    }
}

const inputFields: (TextStuff | OtpStuff)[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions): you can define a base field type, from which all concrete field types can be extended from. And then you simply use the union of those types for the typing of your `inputFields` array, i.e.:

```
interface BaseInputField<T extends string, U extends { [key: string]: any }> {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required?: boolean;
  helper: string;

  // Discrimination happens based on type and templateOptions
  type: T;
  templateOptions: U;
}

type TextInput = BaseInputField<'text', {
  componentProps: {
    placeholder: string;
  }
}>

type OTPInput = BaseInputField<'otp', {
  noOfTextInput: number;
}>;

type InputField = TextInput | OTPInput;

const inputFields: InputField[] = [
  {
    key: 'name', 
    type: 'text', 
    label: `Your Full Name`,
    required: true,
    helper: 'Using your real name would make it more likely for you to get a match',
    templateOptions: { 
      componentProps: {
        placeholder: 'Frank Murphy'
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    key: 'otp', 
    type: 'otp', 
    label: 'Enter OTP',
    helper: '(optional) but try to enter incorrect date', 
    templateOptions: {
      noOfTextInput: 5,
    }
  }
];
```

[See example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=46&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QJIgA4CuYAYsBADYAmAPACrIQAekIlGyGYUoA5gDTIAqg2YRW7AN7IA2gGsIATwBcHLrwC6KuCAXIAvgD5kEgFDJk85au4geAbjPJycAEYUVnG-cdQIARwJgX0oAfhUXAHsI8ghtB3MACwo8aA81WwdHAHos5AARYAwEbgBbUDgwYAiQZAS4PBSQdhdMCEpkauQwBRTkbXbIErxnSAB5PErqjEdulJVaeK6IIZGIccmmlUEHPRMTWZRaJjBcQjBkAF40VtOiUgoaAHJIZkeBU3MECKHqsTAABSgETwGBUH3MyGGiAgCWilFS1l4i12hj2B2Qo1o-1u5yu6CwOPuVGojwiYDwb2MjhAEVGMCOzBxKhABBKbigOwMmXRhLIVEuyAZJ3wRGQAB8MVicZkvk1zqAzkS2CpeQ9pOoBdJHODzJYVI8QHAShBKY5zAd9S8wKaIU5XO5kAADACaEQIUGQxAI5HIyAAckaII6%20GbkL4AkE2iouAQICHbUlyCkoPrBBheMgFG6Pb44L7DcbkAB3N38kpweTIYDnEoRXxOYDyci6GB1zNuroRZA8CDnODIctgBAJN6hwZQsYTKqbYzIUOfb54X7gQHA0FU222qFIWFUBGPYhQbSyZAAWXdeASCke8-0od25j0Am1ob1yFJ5JtEIt77JFOftrOG45D6gAouA0CSv8o4Jsk%204ABTAhseYAJTIC4opcLoYBdn8kGgF8UC%20Ag5yUBUJoAd%20ywTmsU5TGCt40nSQpMsgACs8YQg%20d7qHYQA).